# How to import data from SQL Server into quantmod?

Tags: sql-server, r, quantmod

I'm looking for some guidance and hope that I did the right thing posting it in here. I'm looking to input data to Quantmod with GetSymbols from SQL Server. I'm new to R but have a background working with SQL Server, not a pro but finding my way.
I have imported all my data into one table in SQL Server named Quotes with the following columns;

```
 - Ticker Varchar(10)
 - Name varchar(50)
 - [Date] datetime
 - [Open] Decimal(19,9)
 - High Decimal(19,9)
 - Low Decimal(19,9)
 - [Close] Decimal(19,9)
 - Volume Decimal(19,9)
 - Signal Decimal(19,9)
```

I'm able to connect to the database using the `RODBC` package:

```
 - (cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=localhost;database=DB;trusted_connection=yes;"))
```

and make various select statement in R, but I'm lost in getting the data into Quantmod without having to do other workaround like exporting to csv from SQL. Importing the data from Yahoo is a problem as I cannot find a complete Yahoo-tickerlist.

Is there a way to get data directly into R and `quantmod` from SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
getPrices.DB <- function(Symbol, from=NA) {
    cn <- "add your connection info here"
    qry <- sprintf("select [Date], [Open],[High],[Low],[Close],[Volume],[Signal] from MarketPrice where Ticker = '%s'", Symbol)
    if (!is.na(from)) { qry <- paste(qry, sprintf(" and [Date]>= '%s'", from)) }
    DB <- odbcDriverConnect(cn)
    r <- sqlQuery(DB, qry, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    odbcClose(DB)
    if (!is.null(r) && NROW(r) >= 1) {
        x <- xts(r[, 2:7], order.by = as.POSIXct(r[, 1], tz = "UTC"))#can eliminate tz if you want in local timezone
        indexFormat(x) <- "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%OS3  %z" #option. I find useful for debuggging
        colnames(x) <- paste(Symbol, c("Open", "High","Low", "Close", "Volume", "Signal"), sep = ".")
        return(x)
    } else {
        return(NULL)
    }
}
```

Now hook into the quantmod infrastructure:

```
getSymbols.DB <- function(Symbols, env, ...) {
    importDefaults("getSymbols.DB")
    this.env <- environment()
    for (var in names(list(...))) {assign(var, list(...)[[var]], this.env)}
    if (!hasArg(from)) from <- NA
    if (!hasArg(verbose)) verbose <- FALSE
    if (!hasArg(auto.assign)) auto.assign <- FALSE
    for (i in 1:length(Symbols)) {
        if (verbose) cat(paste("Loading ", Symbols[[i]], paste(rep(".", 10 - nchar(Symbols[[i]])), collapse = ""), sep = ""))
        x <- getPrices.DB(Symbols[[i]], from = from)
        if (auto.assign) assign(Symbols[[i]], x, env)
        if (verbose) cat("done\n")
    }
    if (auto.assign)
        return(Symbols)
    else
        return(x)
}
```

example usage:

```
APPL <- getSymbols("AAPL", src="DB", auto.assign=F)
```

Comment: So close now, I changed the table name from MarketPrice to Quotes. But when using the example I get the following error: `[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified[RODBC] ERROR: state 01S00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attributeODBC connection failed`
`Error in sqlQuery(DB, qry, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : first argument is not an open RODBC channel`

Comment: Ok, got above error due to that I had already stated the odbcdriverconnect in the cn previously and simply removed it from the getPrices.DB area. Now I'm getting stuck in the suggestion example with the following: `Error in `[.data.frame`(r, , 2:7) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: Found the last error also, as the code were missing the "Adjusted" column which is mandatory in the getSymbols and now it works.

Comment: is your rodbc call returning the values as expected? you didn't supply table names, so I  used `MarketPrice`. you should probably test that the query return value is what's expected: `[Date], [Open],[High],[Low],[Close],[Volume],[Signal]`

Comment: Yes, the rodbc call returns the correct value. When running the example I get an error I'm not able to figure out, 'Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("AAPL.Open", "AAPL.High", "AAPL.Low", : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent'. Is there something I could provide to further ease?

Comment: that would be the line `colnames(x) <- paste(Symbol, c("Open", "High","Low", "Close", "Volume", "Signal"), sep = ".")` which renames the columns. you would need to adjust that to match your schema/query output. since you didn't provide an exact schema, this was really meant as a rough example based on what you did provide